# Which format string to displays the float as is?

Tags: c#

I have a float of about 27 significant figures, when I call "ToString()" I get "6.8248054E+26", how do I get the exact normal value?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I clarified the question a little bit

Comment: you are aware that float precision is only 7 significant figure right? That is, you cannot get the 27-digit significant figures which you want! consider using `decimal`

Comment: I don't need float precision, I need a large amount of non-decimal significant figures.

Comment: "I don't need **float** precision"(?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var number = 0.111111111100000000000000000;
string result = String.Format("{0:#,0.###########################}", number);
```

This would show all decimals places up to the 27th, but omits all trailing zeros. So the above number would be displayed as 0.1111111111.

Comment: That looks bad, there are other ways to achieve the same without that long piece of code.

Comment: Which ones? Using F27 always displays 27 digits and doesn't trim trailing zeros

Answer (score 8):

I know you want to display 27-digit significant figure ***and*** you use `float`. You can always do like this:

```
f.ToString("F27");
```

But *really*, **they just don't match**. Consider using `decimal` to achieve that precision:

```
decimal dc = 91.123142141230131231231M; //your 27-digit figure:
dc.ToString("F27");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
number.ToString("F27");
```

Comment: Down voter please include the reason for down voting, it is not fair to down voting without any reason.

Comment: What happens if I try? Why haven't you tried before answering?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Because the OP didn't provide his full code and a test suite, so trying it for OP would be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with what format you use. It rather lies with the precision of the data-type.

From MSDN:

[`float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) has a precision of 7 digits. [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) on the other hand has a precision of 28-29 digits.

That being said, if you assign your value to a variable of type `decimal`, even if you call the `ToString()` method without any string formats, you will get what you want.

```
dc = 6.8248054E+26M;
Console.WriteLine(dc.ToString()); // returns the whole thing including any trailing zero(s)
```

Comment: This answer shares the same idea as mine. ;) upvoted. Yes, I also think that decimal would be needed to retain the precision.

Answer (score -2):

With floats you won't be able to get that precision.

Anyways, you should use the "F" or the "N" formatter, those will print the number as you want.

You can check all the formattings here : [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)